# MYSQL Stored procedure giving null value

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SP with 2 IN and 4 OUT parameters. It's working fine in MYSQL but not when I call using PHP.

Here is my code:

```
try{
            //var_dump($mysqli);
            // bind the first parameter to the session variable @uid
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SET @tid := ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $tid);
            $stmt->execute();

            // bind the second parameter to the session variable @userCount
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SET @mid := ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $memID);
            $stmt->execute();

            // execute the stored procedure
            $sql_1 = 'CALL supplyRSummary(@tid,@mid,@a,@na,@r,@nv)';
            $stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($sql_1);

            // execute the second query to get values from OUT parameter
            $sql_2 = 'SELECT @a,@na,@r,@nv';
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_2);
            $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if ($rows) {
                $a=$rows['a'];
                $na=$rows['na'];
                $r=$rows['r'];
                $nv=$rows['nv'];

                var_dump($a);
            }
        }catch (PDOException $pe){
            die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
        }
```

Here, the `var_dump($a)` gives '`null`' value.

Any advice as to what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You cannot alias the `SELECT` query like that. You have to specify the columns.

Comment: SET @p0='1'; SET @p1='9'; CALL `supplyRSummary`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5); SELECT @p2 AS `a`, @p3 AS `na`, @p4 AS `r`, @p5 AS `nv`;

Comment: The above gives correct result in mysql

Comment: BEGIN
 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO a FROM tbl1 WHERE t_id=tID AND mem_id=mId AND rt_q_a_s !=0;
 
 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO na FROM tbl1 WHERE t_id=tID AND mem_id=mId AND rt_q_na_s !=0;
 
 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO r FROM tbl1 WHERE t_id=tID AND mem_id=mId AND rt_q_r_s !=0;
 
 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nv FROM tbl1 WHERE t_id=tID AND mem_id=mId AND rt_q_a_s =0;
END

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. If you need to make an update to your question click 'edit' and add the extra information.

Comment: ok i got your point jay.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on these two lines:

```
$sql_2 = 'SELECT @a,@na,@r,@nv';
$a=$rows['a'];
```

Plan A:  Change to

```
$sql_2 = 'SELECT @a AS a, @na AS na, @r AS r, @nv AS nv';
$a=$rows['a'];
```

Plan B:  Change to

```
$sql_2 = 'SELECT @a,@na,@r,@nv';
$a=$rows['@a'];
```